# how to move arrows up from vuetify carousel

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have the next carousel made with vuetify and I need to move both arrows up, in order to do that I need to have a `top:0`  in both `v-window__next` and `v-window__prev` class but I don't know how to give the property to the component

[image]

This is a piece of the code

```
                  <v-carousel
                    hide-delimiters
                    height="100%"
                  >
                    <v-carousel-item
                      v-for="(item,i) in yearsMonthsUsed"
                      :key="i"
                    >
                      <v-row
                        class="ma-0"
                        align="center"
                        justify="center"
                      >
                        <v-col
                          cols="12"
                          sm="12"
                          align="center"
                          justify="center"
                        >
                          <div class="text-h6">
                            {{ item.annio }}
                          </div>
                        </v-col>
                        <v-col
                          cols="12"
                          sm="1"
                          v-for="mes in meses"
                          :key="mes.mes"
                        >
                          <v-btn
                            fab
                            depressed
                            x-small
                            :color="pickColor(item.annio,mes.cod)"
                            :class="{'disable-events': true}"
                          >
                            <v-icon>
                              {{ mdiCalendar }}
                            </v-icon>
                          </v-btn>
                          {{ mes.mes.substr(0, 3) }}
                        </v-col>
                      </v-row>
                    </v-carousel-item>
                  </v-carousel>
```

I tried adding Slots inside v-carousel like this

```
 <template v-slot:next="{ on, attrs }" :class="myClas" />

<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .myClas {
  top: 0;
}
</style>
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a class to `v-carousel` and set the style of the arrows from there.

```html
<v-carousel class="myCarousel"><!-- content --></v-carousel>

<style>
.myCarousel .v-window__prev, .myCarousel .v-window__next {
  top: 0;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enter like this onto  or into  style.scss.

> .v-window__prev{
> position: absolute;
> left:-95px;
> top: 0px;
> }